# Angular ngFor with async pipe, tells argument has null type

Tags: angular, typescript, async-pipe

What is the reason for this message

```
Argument of type '[string, { startTime: string; endTime: string; }][] | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Collection<unknown>'.
```

when I try to use `async` pipe in a `ngFor` loop :

```
 <div *ngFor="let slotDay of slots | async | paginate: { id: 'pagination', itemsPerPage: 3, currentPage: p }">
```

with slot being:

```
aaa: Subject<[string, {startTime: string, endTime: string}][]> = new Subject();
```

Does it means that Angular guess that the Subject could return a null value? How to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is `Subject<x>` here? Could you show the code for it? Obviously, there is a type mismatch between `x` and `Collections<Unknown>`

Comment: Can someone tell me what type of array is this `[string, {startTime: string, endTime: string}][]`

Answer (score 0):

check your pipe `paginate` this pipe should be get as argument null or an array and return an array (empty if you want). can you edit your question adding the paginate pipe?.

You can also try to make in two steps your code

```
<ng-container *ngIf="slots|async as slotsAsync">
   <div *ngFor="let slotDay of slotsAsync | 
           paginate: { id: 'pagination', itemsPerPage: 3, currentPage: p }">
    ...
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Note: for [a convention](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables), the variables that was observables is named ending with $, better stols$ than slots (it's not mandatory but help to undestand for anyone)